# how can I put a React component in a typescript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

That works if I define the type of "component" as any:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { WEB_APP_TOKEN_KEY } from './auth.api';


export interface IAuthRouteProps {
    component: any // React.Component
    path: string
}

const AuthRoute: React.FC<IAuthRouteProps> = (props) => {

    if (!localStorage.getItem(WEB_APP_TOKEN_KEY)) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Route component={props.component} path={props.path} />;
};

export default AuthRoute;
```

this is how it is used

```
 <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}/>
          <AuthRoute path="/cars" component={CarPage}/>
 </Switch>
```

In the interface I would like to have typed the item "componenten" not as "any" but as a React component. is that possible?

Comment: `React.ComponentType`?

Comment: wow perfect. My request is still warm and already resolved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it the same way you declare a functional component with all the needed props:

```js
export interface IAuthRouteProps {
    component: React.FC<MainPageProps | CarPageProps>
    path: string
}
```

If you don't want to be so precise of the type of component that you want (`MainPage` or `CarPage`), just use `React.FC` without a generic declaration.

Comment: You likely don't want to limit yourself to only functional components.

Comment: If he only use functional component it's totally fine and it would be worst if he use the global `React.ComponentType` :/ It's better to be the as precise as possible.

Comment: All allowed components to be included in an enumeration via React.FC <T> is even better. Thank you for that.

Comment: Mmmh but it's less accurate. If only the `MainPage` and the `CarPage` should be authenticate then it's better to declare them like that. So you are sure that no other components than `MainPage` and `CarPage` are going to be passed in the prop.

Comment: I just tried this and realized that I misunderstood it. How can define CarPageProps?

Comment: Same way than `IAuthRouteProps`. Don't forget to export the interface and import it in the `AuthRoute` component file.

Comment: Please don't forget to `upvote` if it was useful and `validate` it if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface IAuthRouteProps {
    component: JSX.Element
    path: string 
}
```